# super() takes 2 same class but returns another class's method

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I have some problem with syntax of Python's super function..

```
class x:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class p(x):
    def __init__(self):
        print(super(p,self).__init__())
```

output:

```
<bound method x.__init__ of <__main__.y object at 0x000001FF918EC898>>
```

This is `__init__` method of `x`.
So problem is that, `self` is `p` itself in `p`.We call `super(p,self)`, and with this way we giving `p` class two times to super function , but it returns `x`'s `__init__` method..
How??

Comment: `self` is not `p`, it is _an instance_ of `p`. `p` knows its parent class(es), that's how `super` finds the `__init__` of `x`.

Comment: short and powerfull answer.Thank you so much.